# Google Play crash LibGDX project

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I have succesfully implemented the Google Play Game Service (this tutorial help me: [Invader360Tutorial](https://github.com/TheInvader360/libgdx-gameservices-tutorial))

But now I stand for a new problem. I have the `ActionResolver` Interface created and implemented in the `coreproject.java` 
here:

```
ActionResolver actionResolver;

public myGame(ActionResolver actionResolver){

    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;

}
```

In the next function, I use this:

```
actionResolver.submitScoreGPGS(100);
```

And this crashes my game. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please post more information about the error, e.g. a stack trace.

Comment: logcat show me the googleapiclient is not connected but i connected if i start my game. i have the same code as here [link](https://github.com/TheInvader360/libgdx-gameservices-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-libgdx-gameservices-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/gameservices/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace. We can't help you without knowing why it crashes.

Comment: i found the problem. it was a fail in the developer console. the package name does not match

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Package name does not match.